Do multi-acceptance/multi-language automata exist in literature?
A multi-acceptance deterministic finite state automaton is a tuple $(Q,\Sigma,\delta,q_0,T,f)$ where

$Q$, $\Sigma$, $\delta: Q \times \Sigma \to Q$, and $q_0 \in Q$ are defined in the standard way of DFAs;
$T$ is a finite set of labels;
$f: Q \to 2^L$ is a function that associates a set of labels to each state.

$\delta^{\\*}: Q \times \Sigma^{\\*} \to Q$ is defined in the standard way.
Such automaton recognizes $|T|$ languages, one for each label in $T$. More specifically, given a label $t \in T$
$$
L(t) = \{x \mid f(\delta^{\\*}(q_0, x)) \ni t \}
$$
or if you prefer
$$
L(t) = \{x \mid t \in f(\delta^{\\*}(q_0, x)) \}
$$
Does this concept exists in literature? Googling "multi-acceptance DFA" and similar queries did not yield anything useful.

The reason I want to use this kind of automata is the following.
I have several classes of regular languages , e.g. $L_1, L_2: T \to 2^{\Sigma^{\\*}}$, which I already need to represent as DFAs, and I need to compute their union $L: T \to 2^{\Sigma^{\\*}}$ defined as
$L(t) = \{L_1(t) \cup L_2(t)\}$.
I think operations such as the union can be more efficient if I have a single automaton for each class of languages, instead of an automaton for each $L(t)$.
Moreover, given the context in which I'm working, one can expect that many languages $L(t)$ and $L(t')$ are the same or have common aspects.
Do you suggest other approaches?

Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_machine, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke_structure_(model_checking)

@D.W. Thanks, I had never heard of Moore machines. Coincidentally, I this classes of languages are used as an alternative (partial) representation of epistemic states, which are usually represented as Kripke structures.

There have been studies on something called colored finite automata, which seem very close to your definition. Other colored models, e.g. regular expressions, also exist.
I haven't work on this personally so I'm not informed on the literature, but they are studied e.g. in https://doi.org/10.1587/transinf.2021FCP0012
